# Using CreateCompatibleDC with CScrollView

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, desktop-application

My English is not perfect.
I am using CScrollView as base of CIDEView. This IDE has syntax highlight, so, if I type start comment, a lot of lines change its color, so I must rewrite the full window, this is very flickering. So, I thought I wrote the window to memory, after it, I copy the window to the display. But I does not see the characters what I type, I see only the caret. Example code:

```
void CIDEView::OnDraw(CDC *pDC) {
    CPoint  const pos = GetDeviceScrollPosition();
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    OffsetRect(&rect, pos.x, pos.y);
    CDC dc;
    if  (! dc.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC))
        MessageBox(L"CreateCompatibleDC is failed");
    auto    const oldfont = dc.SelectObject(&font);
    dc.FillSolidRect(rect, 0);
    // Example Writing
    dc.TextOutW(pos.x, pos.y, L"¶", 1);
    dc.SelectObject(oldfont);
    pDC->BitBlt(pos.x, pos.y, rect.right - pos.x, rect.bottom - pos.y, &dc, pos.x, pos.y, SRCCOPY);
}

void CIDEView::OnInitialUpdate() {
    CScrollView::OnInitialUpdate();
    SetScrollSizes(MM_TEXT, {linewidth, GetDocument()->lines * lineheight});
}
```

By the way, if the file has 20 pages, will it use 20-times memory than the desktop? 3840*2160 is 8 M pixels, 1G color: 32 MB, so this means 640 MB!

Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to create a compatible bitmap and select that into your memory DC. That bitmap needs only to be the size of the actual viewport, not the entire document.

Comment: A memory-DC (or DC in general) in itself does not use any significant amount of memory space. And the original bitmap it contains is a tiny one. From the [CreateCompatibleDC()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createcompatibledc) documentation: _'When the memory DC is created, its display surface is exactly one monochrome pixel wide and one monochrome pixel high'_.

Comment: Thank you. I used an another solution: I do no clear the background, and the background mode is OPAQUE, not TRANSPARENT. This stops flickering.